# How to read a large file in chunks?

Tags: python, io

I am trying to write a loop to iterate over a very large file, I am writing this script in a linux vm with 4GB of ram so I can't load the whole file at once I need to read it in chunks of 1024 bytes (correct me if wrong please)

I can think of two ways to do this although the second one gets killed by `zsh`
because the system simply runs out of ram

the first one keeps returning the same list of passwords

```
wordlist_handler = open('passwords.txt')

def read_wordlist(wordlist_handler):
    return wordlist_handler.read(1024)
    

def read_wordlist2(file='passwords.txt'): 
    with open(file , 'r') as f:
        return list(f)
```

my goal is to iterate over the file similar to the first method

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this will return a list of n passwords 
    
    while True:
        lst = read_wordlist(wordlist_handler)
        
        # use lst in concurrent.futures
```

Comment: IT is a clear text file - read it line by line - that way you only have one line in memory at any time.: `with open("passwords.txt") as f:  for line in f: ....` do something with that line. Do NOT return it - use it and if it does not work you'll get the next line...

Comment: @PatrickArtner the goal is to use ``` concurrent.futures ``` single lines are usesless here i think

Answer (score -1):

I have this but some of the passwords are 2 digits long

```
while True:
        x = load_chunks()
        print (len(x) , x )
        if len(x) <= 2 :
            break
```

Comment: 1st not an answer, 2nd missing `load_chunks()`, 3rd why ask if you got a solution.  If you want to add more to you question - [edit] it instead.